# Regex: Put quotation marks around each line

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
content ='''38%
46%
54%
62% 
70% 
78% 
86%'''
```

I want to wrap quotation marks around the values in each line.  My attempt to do so is like so:

```
formatted_answers = re.sub("([^\s]+)", "'\1'", content)
print(formatted_answers)
```

But this returns

```
''
''
''
'' 
'' 
'' 
''
```

Can't see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: This string `"'\1'"` is parsed by the language as `'` plus the octal character `001` plus another `'` So you are substituting a quoted control-1 character. Double escape the escape like this `"'\\1'"` and it will feed the quoted backreference `'\1'` as the replacefment.

Comment: Likewise, `"([^\s]+)"` is being parsed as `([^s]+)` but it works because you don't have any `s` in the source you show. So obviously `"(.*)"` is better since it matches horizontally any character.

Comment: Thats odd @WiktorStribiżew you've marked this as a duplicate of `Python re.sub back reference not back referencing [duplicate]` which is also markedd as a duplicate. Why a duplicate of a duplicate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put raw string (`r`) as second parameter in `re.sub()`:

```
content ='''38%
46%
54%
62%
70%
78%
86%'''

formatted_answers = re.sub("([^\s]+)", r"'\1'", content)  # <-- r here!
print(formatted_answers)
```

Prints:

```
'38%'
'46%'
'54%'
'62%'
'70%'
'78%'
'86%'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if there are spaces anywhere in the content, it will wrap quotes around every object with spaces. `'$796' 'a' 'week'` Do you know how to wrap quotes only around the first and end of each line?

Comment: Nevermind, I just replaced the match with: `(.*)`